# Hadoop directory file to user folder

Tags: hadoop, centos, hdfs

I have created a folder in the root directly and I'm trying to copy a folder to hdfs hadoop but I'm getting an error message. This is the steps that I have followed:

```
[root@dh] ls
XXdirectoryXX
[root@dh] sudo –u hdfs hadoop fs –mkdir /user/uname
[root@hd] uname
[root@hd] sudo –u hdfs hadoop fs –chown uname /user/uname
[root@hd] su - uname
[uname@hd] hadoop fs –copyFromLocal XXdirectoryXX/ /user/uname
copyFromLocal: 'XXdirectoryXX/': No such file or directory
```

Is there a problem in the command or what I've done or should I use another command to copy the files over?

I'm using Centos 6.8 in the machine

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Does this dir/file (XXdirectoryXX/) exists

Comment: I can see it from root when I run ls

Comment: But you run the command from uname user not root user

Comment: From root doesn't work either: permission denied

Comment: Can you give full permission to folder and files inside that folder?

Comment: Instead of giving "XXdirectoryXX" path on copyFromLocal provide full path from /soemthing/something/XXdirectoryXX and try that without having / at the end.

Comment: The local path which you are mentioning is wrong. Please give full path from root (i.e /) to XXdirectoryXX and execute.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the comments I've managed to resolve the issue. Here is the code it it helps someone:

```
[root@dh] sudo -u hdfs hadoop fs -chown -R root /user/uname
[root@dh] hadoop fs –copyFromLocal XXdirectoryXX/ /user/uname
```

Regards